# .Net Core - referencing another project in solution prevents System and other dependencies from being recognised

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a solution that contains a number of projects, one is an API, the other is an admin portal.

I'm trying to create another project inside the solution to hold all shared components such as database entities so they can be shared between the API and the Admin Portal.

I've created a new project called 'Common' and selected to use netcoreapp2.2 because if I just select a standard class library then annotations on the Entities don't work.

When I reference the 'Common' project from the 'API' project, which is also netcoreapp2.2, Rider(Mac) is unable to recognise any of the standard packaged used with the project such as System and System.Linq (and many others).

My experience with .Net Core is limited to only this project, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: If you remove your reference on 'Common', and if you add a reference on System.Linq in the three projects, can you successfully build each of them ?

Comment: This is fairly broad making it hard to help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, I removed the 'Common' project from my solution and re-created it this time selecting the create the project as a Web Application.